# Java: Read remote XML that requires logging in

Tags: java, spring-boot, remote-access, jcifs

I have a Spring Boot app which requires to read an XML file that's available online (via https) but requires logging in (it's generated by the RedMine API, if that helps). I have an account with username and password tested and working (can log in via a browser) and I'm trying to use JCIFS as shown below but I'm hitting a "connection timed out" error (the XML file is definitely available at the time). What am I doing wrong?

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, USERNAME, PASSWORD);  
      
try (InputStream is = new SmbFile("https://mypath/issues.xml?limit=100", auth).getInputStream()) {
            System.out.println(is.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle IOException
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this without any third party libraries, see this blog post:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-url-connection

and a short example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

public class AuthenticationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://mypath/issues.xml?limit=100";
        String user = "user";
        String password = "pass";

        String auth = user + ":" + password;
        byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String authHeaderValue = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        int len = -1;

        URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeaderValue);

        try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((len = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                builder.append(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That results in javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: received handshake warning: unrecognized_name, even though the username is 100% correct.

Comment: the message "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: received handshake warning: unrecognized_name" is likely not related to java or the username but to the configuration of your host/webserver. If "mypath" is the real host you are using, make sure that a proper configuration for certificates, server names and certificate chains is in place!